# US: under what conditions can information about a missed payment be shared with credit bureaus?

Tags: florida, rent, credit-report

Let's say I notified a property manager that as a tenant I'm withholding rent because of a breach of contract. He starts a collection process: it goes into credit reports, just like that? I live in Florida.

Comment: What does the quoted paragraph 4 have to do with the question?

Comment: @phoog In hindsight it shouldn't, it's an oversight.

Comment: It seems that you are asking whether the missing payment can go into a credit report, even though the payment is missing because of a dispute about a breach on contract. Is that right?

Comment: That sounds very much like an existing Q; voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: @Erwann: If you feel your Q is different from the one I linked, please edit your Q to clarify.

Comment: Also, I edited to remove the FTC quotation, as you wrote that including it was an oversight. Again, feel free to re-edit as required.

Comment: @sleske the suggested seems like it could answer my question. I just need to wrap my head around it. So yesm you may close this one, and I'll reopen if it turns out to be a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Non-payment can be reported to a credit bureau, you have a right in the U.S. to file an explanation with it or to have it corrected if what is said isn't true. If the statement is that you haven't paid rent and you haven't, it is true.